# 1 equation of two unknowns and their number of digits --- how many (x, y) exist?

Tags: linear-algebra

> X is a two-digit positive integer and Y is a three digit positive integer. If X is increased by Y% and Y is decreased by X%, they equal one another. How many solutions of (X, Y) are there for this case?

Source: [Bangladesh Mathematical Olympiad 2016](http://www.matholympiad.org.bd/)

---

So...

- X has 2 digits; Y has 3.
- $$x(1+\frac{y}{100})=y(1-\frac{x}{100})\\x+\frac{xy}{100}=y-\frac{xy}{100}\\x-y=-\frac{xy}{100}-\frac{xy}{100}\\x-y=\frac{-2xy}{100}\\50(x-y)=-xy\\50x-50y+xy=0\\50x+xy=50y\\x(50+y)=50y\\\boxed{x=\frac{50y}{50+y}}$$

I can't go any further.

*** *In some places, I might be elaborating the work unnecessarily. Feel free to remove some lines if you feel a terse version would be more comfortable to work with.*

Answer (score 1):

if your last equation is true, you can write $$x=50-\frac{2500}{50+y}$$

Answer (score 0):

From your final equation you can use the fact that $100 \le y \lt 1000$ to determine $34 \le x \le 47$.  You could also get $$y=\frac {50x}{50-x}$$ which tells us that $x \lt 50$ and all of the divisors of $50-x$ are also divisors of $50$.  This means that $50-x$ can only be $1,2,4,5,8,10,16,20,25,32$ and using the restriction on $x$ we are down to $50-x$ being among $4,5,8,10,16$  We can just see which give an integral $y$ and find that $50-x$ must be $4,5,10$, giving 
$$\begin {array} {c c}x&y\\46&575\\45&450\\40&200 \end {array}$$